# Is it possible read the content of a variable with gdb?

Tags: gdb, reverse-engineering

Is it possible without any file.out and source code, but just the binary?
Is it possible, knowing the name of a var, found and read at runtime the value?

Comment: possibly, if it was compiled with debug symbols. if not, you won't know how to find it. anyway, since you don't have the source, how will you know where to put the breakpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible, knowing the name of a var, found and read at runtime the value

It depends.

If the variable is a global, and the binary is not stripped, then you should be able to examine its value with a simple

```
x/gx &var
print var
```

The latter may print the variable as if it were of type `int` (if the binary has no debug info), which may not be what you are looking for.

If the variable is local (automatic), then you can print it only while inside the routine in which it is declared (obviously).

If the binary has debug info, then simple `print var` in correct context should work.

If the binary doesn't, you'll have to figure out the in-memory address of the variable (usually at fixed offset from stack pointer of frame pointer register), and examine that address. You can often figure out a lot about the given routine by disassembling it.

Update:

> if I strip the binary, is harder to do the reverse engineering?

Sure: the less info you provide to the attacker, the harder you make his job.

But you also make *your* job harder: when your binary doesn't work, often your end-user will know more about his system than you do. Often he will load your binary into GDB, and tell you exactly where your bug is. With a stripped executable, he likely wouldn't be able to do that, so you'll guess back and forth, and after a week of trying will lose that customer.

And there is *nothing* you can do to prevent a sufficiently determined and sufficiently skilled hacker with root access to his system and hardware from reverse engineering your program.

In the end, in my experience, anti-circumvention techniques are usually much more trouble than they are worth.

Comment: One question about the security: if I strip the binary, is harder to do the reverse engineering?
Thank you.